# Running Teradatasql driver for python code using spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, teradata

I want write code fetch data from teradata using python. The code should work while running using spark on cluster as well as local. While running using spark I don't want to open connections on executors. So the plan is to run code on driver using teradatasql package. Since teradatasql packages so library I thought I don't have install teradata library on cluster.

I packaged the dependencies i.e. teradatasql as egg file and passed it as --py-files. But while running on code teradatasql is not able to read library from egg file.

Os error: teradatasql.so cannot open shared object file. Not a directory.

I followed the below steps to package the egg file.
1. pip install teradatasql --target./src # note all my code is in src folder. Doing this step will install teradatasql package in my src folder. it contains teradatasql.so library
2. In setup.py packages=find_packages('src'), package_data={'teradatasql':['teradatasql.so']}
3. python setup.py bdist_eggg

Comment: Please share how you have generated your egg file, so we can have more details about it

Comment: I shared the steps

Answer (score 0):

The teradatasql driver uses a shared library to communicate with the Teradata Database.

The teradatasql driver will not work if you repackage just the Python file portion of the driver. The error will occur that you got.

The intended use of the teradatasql driver is that you install it into your Python environment with the command: pip install teradatasql

We will not be able to effectively support you if you take apart and repackage the teradatasql driver. That is not a supported use case.

Comment: I updated my question with the steps i followed to generate egg. Along with python portion of the driver and i also packaged teradatasql.so in my egg using package_data option of setup.py. I checked the generated egg and found teradatasql.so under teradatasql folder. May be as it is part of zip(egg) the library is not getting recognized. Also as you said this is not the intended use, I will try to use it directly. Can you also please let me know if there is a way to use a connection pool with teradatasql. In our organization there is a limit on the number of connections.